# mailbox always empty when checking emails via imap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

Our platform is regularly checking some of our clients mailbox looking for answered emails, so far it's been working perfectly but we recently got a client with a strange issue.

When i connect to the IMAP server and search for email on a given period of time (for instance all mails from yesterday), i just get an empty list. But when i check with the client on its mailbox i can see the mail received from yesterday. Her mail client was configured to use POP so i asked her to change to IMAP as POP is supposed to remove email from the mail server. Now she is using IMAP but i still can not see anything on the mail server.

To connect to the IMAP server i am using those instructions:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(server, port, ssl, nil, false) # OK
imap.login(login, pwd) # Authentification Successful
imap.select("INBOX") # Mailbox is OK
```

To look for email from yesterday i am using those criteria:

```
imap.search(["SEEN","SINCE","Sep-07-2015"]
imap.search(["SEEN","SINCE","Sep-07-2015"]
```

I even tried to look into other mailbox in case her mail didn't arrive on Inbox, i have listed her mailboxes with imap.list('*', '*') even so i can not find any mails. It feels her entire mailbox is empty on the server. Yet i can see her emails on the mail client.

I am at loss on this case and was wondering if anyone has an idea of what could be happening preventing me from discovering any emails via IMAP?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have incorrect date format: it should be similar to `8-Aug-2002` and not `Aug-8-2002`. Look [here](http://devdocs.io/ruby/net/imap#method-i-search) for other options. If that doesn't help, try some easier search with a more broader criteria, something like `imap.search(['SUBJECT', 'hello'])` and use instead of `hello` some real subject.
[This article](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/ruby-search-imap-mail-server-using-multiple-search-fields) also may help.
Cheers!

Comment: Actually i was wrong, my system does use Aug-8-2002 format date, it is just i was desperate and tried something else and forgot to put paste the correct format. I did try a simpler search criteria like subject but still no results :(
Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntaxe in php , example for yahoo

```
$inbox='{imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox';
$mbox = imap_open($inbox,$username,$password);
imap_search($mbox, 'SINCE "'.date('d M Y',strtotime("-1 days")).'"');
```